# Angular 2 aux routes (when there are nested modules)

Tags: angular, module, routes

I am having a hard time working on the solution. I was looking for answers but with not much luck. Everything on examples is direct from root component and pretty simple. So here is my problem.

I will draw diagram of my modules, for better understanding.
[image]

And here are module routes:
    **AppModule**

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error.component';

import {mainFrameRoutes} from './components/main-frame/main-frame.routing';

const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
  { path: '', redirectTo : 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
, { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/components/login/login.module#LoginModule'}
,  ...mainFrameRoutes
//, { path: 'main-frame', loadChildren: 'app/components/main-frame/main-frame.module#MainFrameModule'}
,{ path: '**', component:ErrorComponent}
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**MainFrameModule**

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { MainFrameComponent } from './main-frame.component';
import { DashboardNavComponent } from './dashboard-nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';

import { ProductsComponent } from '../products/products.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from '../error.component';



export const mainFrameRoutes:Routes = [
  { path: 'main-frame', component : MainFrameComponent,
      children : [
       { path:'', redirectTo : '/main-frame/home',pathMatch:'full'}
      ,{ path:'home', component : HomeComponent}
      ,{ path: 'products',component:ProductsComponent,loadChildren :'app/components/products/products.module#ProductsModule'}
      ,{ path:'account', loadChildren : 'app/components/account/account.module#AccountModule'}
      ,{ path:'billing', loadChildren : 'app/components/billing/billing.module#BillingModule'}
      ,{ path:'affiliate',loadChildren : 'app/components/affiliate/affiliate.module#AffiliateModule'} 
      ]
  }
  ,{path: "**", component: ErrorComponent}
];


export const mainFrameRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(mainFrameRoutes);
```

**BillingModule**

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { BillingComponent } from './billing.component';
import { BillingCreditHistoryComponent } from './billing-credit-history.component';
import { BillingAddNewComponent } from './billing-add-new.component';
import { BillingAddNewSidebarComponent } from './add-new-sidebar.component';


const billingRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: BillingComponent, 
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo : 'new', pathMatch : 'full'}
           ,{ path: 'history', component: BillingCreditHistoryComponent}
           ,{ path: 'new', component: BillingAddNewComponent}
           ,{ path: 'new-sidebar', component: BillingAddNewSidebarComponent, outlet:'sidebar'}
        ]}
];


export const billingRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(billingRoutes);
```

So i am trying to navigate to BillingModule and render both frame (MainFrameModule), main Billing Content and Sidebar Content.
Like this :
 **localhost:3000/main-frame/billing/new(sidebar:new-sidebar)**

 The error that i am getting is :

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'new-sidebar'
```

And this is template in which i am trying to place that content:

**BillingComponent template:**

```html
 <div class="page__content-inner">
    
     <div class="page__main-col">
               
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>

     <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**I am struggling with this too much time. Help me if you can.**

Comment: Were you ever able to direct nested module's outlet to a named outlet?